# Spark SQL replacement for MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of two string type columns `(username, friend)` and for each username, I want to collect all of its friends on one row, concatenated as strings. For example: `('username1', 'friends1, friends2, friends3')`

I know MySQL does this with `GROUP_CONCAT`. Is there any way to do this with Spark SQL?

Comment: If you are using Spark 2.4+, you can do this with a combination of `collect_list()` and `array_join()`. No need for UDFs. For the details, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472764/877069).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Before you proceed: This operations is yet another another `groupByKey`. While it has multiple legitimate applications it is relatively expensive so be sure to use it only when required.

---

Not exactly concise or efficient solution but you can use `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` introduced in Spark 1.5.0:

```scala
object GroupConcat extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", StringType)
    def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("buff", ArrayType(StringType))
    def dataType = StringType
    def deterministic = true 

    def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
      buffer.update(0, ArrayBuffer.empty[String])
    }

    def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
      if (!input.isNullAt(0)) 
        buffer.update(0, buffer.getSeq[String](0) :+ input.getString(0))
    }

    def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
      buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getSeq[String](0) ++ buffer2.getSeq[String](0))
    }

    def evaluate(buffer: Row) = UTF8String.fromString(
      buffer.getSeq[String](0).mkString(","))
}
```

Example usage:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("username1", "friend1"),
  ("username1", "friend2"),
  ("username2", "friend1"),
  ("username2", "friend3")
)).toDF("username", "friend")

df.groupBy($"username").agg(GroupConcat($"friend")).show

## +---------+---------------+
## | username|        friends|
## +---------+---------------+
## |username1|friend1,friend2|
## |username2|friend1,friend3|
## +---------+---------------+
```

You can also create a Python wrapper as shown in [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33233737/1560062)

In practice it can be faster to extract RDD, `groupByKey`, `mkString` and rebuild DataFrame.

You can get a similar effect by combining `collect_list` function (Spark >= 1.6.0) with `concat_ws`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, udf, lit}

df.groupBy($"username")
  .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"friend")).alias("friends"))
```

Comment: What If I want to use it In SQL How can I register this UDF in Spark SQL?

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala [There is `register` method which accepts UDAFS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/37c617e4f580482b59e1abbe3c0c27c7125cf605/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L63-L69) so it should work as standard UDF.

Comment: @zero323 any approach to do the same in spark sql 1.4.1

Comment: Can't you remove ` UTF8String.fromString()` in evaluate function?

Comment: This is a v. good solution. I tried it after a couple of modifications and worked fine *except* I was getting compatibility issues with the resulting DF. I could not compare the columns produced with other columns without getting UTF exceptions. I changed to converting the DF to an RDD; doing what I wanted and then converting it back to a DF. This fixed all problems and, in addition, the solution was 10x faster. I think that it is safe to say that `udfs` should be avoided if and when possible.

Answer (score 29):

In Spark 2.4+ you can get similar behavior to MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) and Redshift's [`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) with the help of `collect_list()` and `array_join()`, without the need for any UDFs.

Here's a demonstration in PySpark, though the code should be very similar for Scala too:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_join, sort_array, collect_list

friends = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('jacques', 'nicolas'),
        ('jacques', 'georges'),
        ('jacques', 'francois'),
        ('bob', 'amelie'),
        ('bob', 'zoe'),
    ],
    schema=['username', 'friend'],
)

(
    friends
    .groupBy('username')
    .agg(
        array_join(
            sort_array(
                collect_list('friend'),
                asc=False,
            ),
            delimiter=', ',
        ).alias('friends')
    )
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```

In Spark SQL the solution is likewise:

```sql
SELECT
    username,
    array_join(
        sort_array(
            collect_list(friend),
            false
        ),
        ', '
    ) AS friends
FROM friends
GROUP BY username;
```

Here's the output:

```
+--------+--------------------------+
|username|friends                   |
+--------+--------------------------+
|jacques |nicolas, georges, francois|
|bob     |zoe, amelie               |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

Note that if you want the joined elements to appear in a particular order, you should rely on one of the array sorting functions like [`sort_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html) or [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort.html) (they are different) rather than on `ORDER BY`. That's because [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) will order the results in a non-deterministic way.

Answer (score 25):

You can try the collect_list function

```
sqlContext.sql("select A, collect_list(B), collect_list(C) from Table1 group by A
```

Or you can regieter a UDF something like

```
sqlContext.udf.register("myzip",(a:Long,b:Long)=>(a+","+b))
```

and you can use this function in the query

```
sqlConttext.sql("select A,collect_list(myzip(B,C)) from tbl group by A")
```

Comment: `collect_set` will work too, will return only unique values

Comment: `collect_list` and `collect_set` are awesome Spark SQL functions! [spark-sql > sql-ref-functions-builtin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a function you can use in PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def group_concat(col, distinct=False, sep=','):
    if distinct:
        collect = F.collect_set(col.cast(StringType()))
    else:
        collect = F.collect_list(col.cast(StringType()))
    return F.concat_ws(sep, collect)


table.groupby('username').agg(F.group_concat('friends').alias('friends'))
```

In SQL:

```
select username, concat_ws(',', collect_list(friends)) as friends
from table
group by username
```

Answer (score 4):

-- the spark SQL resolution with collect_set

```sql
SELECT id, concat_ws(', ', sort_array( collect_set(colors))) as csv_colors
FROM ( 
  VALUES ('A', 'green'),('A','yellow'),('B', 'blue'),('B','green') 
) as T (id, colors)
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it with pyspark < 1.6, which unfortunately doesn't support user-defined aggregate function:

```
byUsername = df.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + ", " + y)
```

and if you want to make it a dataframe again:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(byUsername, ["username", "friends"])
```

As of 1.6, you can use [collect_list](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) and then join the created list:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
join_ = F.udf(lambda x: ", ".join(x), StringType())
df.groupBy("username").agg(join_(F.collect_list("friend").alias("friends"))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Language**: Scala
**Spark version**: 1.5.2

I had the same issue and also tried to resolve it using `udfs` but, unfortunately, this has led to more problems later in the code due to type inconsistencies. I was able to work my way around this by first converting the `DF` to an `RDD` then **grouping by** and manipulating the data in the desired way and then converting the `RDD` back to a `DF` as follows:

```
val df = sc
     .parallelize(Seq(
        ("username1", "friend1"),
        ("username1", "friend2"),
        ("username2", "friend1"),
        ("username2", "friend3")))
     .toDF("username", "friend")

+---------+-------+
| username| friend|
+---------+-------+
|username1|friend1|
|username1|friend2|
|username2|friend1|
|username2|friend3|
+---------+-------+

val dfGRPD = df.map(Row => (Row(0), Row(1)))
     .groupByKey()
     .map{ case(username:String, groupOfFriends:Iterable[String]) => (username, groupOfFriends.mkString(","))}
     .toDF("username", "groupOfFriends")

+---------+---------------+
| username| groupOfFriends|
+---------+---------------+
|username1|friend2,friend1|
|username2|friend3,friend1|
+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below python-based code that achieves group_concat functionality.

Input Data:

Cust_No,Cust_Cars

1, Toyota

2, BMW

1, Audi

2, Hyundai

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').getOrCreate()

# Udf to join all list elements with "|"
def combine_cars(car_list,sep='|'):
  collect = sep.join(car_list)
  return collect

test_udf = udf(combine_cars,StringType())
car_list_per_customer.groupBy("Cust_No").agg(F.collect_list("Cust_Cars").alias("car_list")).select("Cust_No",test_udf("car_list").alias("Final_List")).show(20,False)
```

Output Data:
Cust_No, Final_List

1, Toyota|Audi

2, BMW|Hyundai

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Spark SQL function collect_list and after you will need to cast to string and use the function regexp_replace to replace the special characters.

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(cast(collect_list((column)) as string), ' ', ''), ',', '|'), '[^A-Z0-9|]', '')
```

it's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Higher order function **`concat_ws()`** and **`collect_list()`** can be a good alternative along with **`groupBy()`**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
df_grp = df.groupby("agg_col").agg(F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.time)).alias("time"), F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.status)).alias("status"), F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.llamaType)).alias("llamaType"))
```

**Sample Output**

```
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|agg_col|time              |status          |llamaType            |
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|1      |5-1-2020#;6-2-2020|Running#;Sitting|red llama#;blue llama|
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```