# Is Spark SQL UDAF (user defined aggregate function) available in the Python API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As of Spark 1.5.0 it seems possible to write your own UDAF's for custom aggregations on DataFrames:
[Spark 1.5 DataFrame API Highlights: Date/Time/String Handling, Time Intervals, and UDAFs](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html)

It is however unclear to me if this functionality is supported in the Python API?

Comment: No, it is not supported. You can call Scala UDAF but it is not pretty. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33257733/1560062) to [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33233737/1560062) for a full example.

Comment: @zero323 so is it now availaible in 1.6 spark or 1.61?

Comment: @stackit Neither 1.6.x nor 2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot defined Python UDAF in Spark 1.5.0-2.0.0. There is a JIRA tracking this feature request:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10915

resolved with goal "later" so it probably won't happen anytime soon.

You can use Scala UDAF from PySpark - it is described [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33233737)