# Calculate centroid of a set of coordinates on a PySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, geospatial

I have a dataframe similar to

```
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
| cod| name|sum_vol|  date|   lat|   lon|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
|aggc|23124|     37|201610|-15.42|-32.11|
|aggc|23124|     19|201611|-15.42|-32.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201610|-26.42|-43.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201611|-26.42|-43.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201610|-22.42|-46.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201611|-22.42|-46.11|
| tty|  231|     25|201610|-25.42|-42.11|
| tty|  231|     45|201611|-25.42|-42.11|
|xptx|  124|     62|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|  124|    260|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
```

Where for each name I have a few different lat lon on the same dataframe. I would like to use the `shapely` function to calculate the centroid for each user:

```
Point(lat, lon).centroid()
```

This UDF would be able to calculate it:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
def f(x):
    return list(MultiPoint(tuple(x.values)).centroid.coords[0])

get_centroid = udf(lambda x: f(x), DoubleType())
```

But how can I apply it to a list of coordinates of each user? It seems that a [UDAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502263/is-spark-sql-udaf-user-defined-aggregate-function-available-in-the-python-api) on a group by is not a viable solution in this case.

Comment: Trying to do something similar for grouping events based on how close they occurred geographically, were you able to find a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want:

- Execute 3rd party plain Python function
- Which is not associative or commutative

The only choice you have is:

- group records (you can use `RDD.groupBy` or `collect_list`).
- apply the function.
- flatMap (RDD) or join (DF).