# How to use Scala UDF in PySpark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to be able to use a Scala function as a UDF in PySpark

```scala
package com.test

object ScalaPySparkUDFs extends Serializable {
    def testFunction1(x: Int): Int = { x * 2 }
    def testUDFFunction1 = udf { x: Int => testFunction1(x) }
}
```

I can access `testFunction1` in PySpark and have it return values:

```py
functions = sc._jvm.com.test.ScalaPySparkUDFs 
functions.testFunction1(10)
```

What I want to be able to do is use this function as a UDF, ideally in a `withColumn` call:

```py
row = Row("Value")
numbers = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4]).map(row).toDF()
numbers.withColumn("Result", testUDFFunction1(numbers['Value']))
```

I think a promising approach is as found here:
[Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)

However, when making the changes to code found there to use `testUDFFunction1` instead:

```py
def udf_test(col):
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    _f = sc._jvm.com.test.ScalaPySparkUDFs.testUDFFunction1.apply
    return Column(_f(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))
```

I get:

```
 AttributeError: 'JavaMember' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

I don't understand this because I believe `testUDFFunction1` does have an apply method?

I do not want to use expressions of the type found here:
[Register UDF to SqlContext from Scala to use in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479892/register-udf-to-sqlcontext-from-scala-to-use-in-pyspark)

Any suggestions as to how to make this work would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you've linked is using a Scala `object`. Scala `object` is a singleton and you can use `apply` method directly.

Here you use a nullary function which returns an object of `UserDefinedFunction`  class co you have to call the function first:

```py
_f = sc._jvm.com.test.ScalaPySparkUDFs.testUDFFunction1() # Note () at the end
Column(_f.apply(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))
```

Comment: Is there something similar if I want to pass multiple columns.

Comment: @zero323 , would you please guide me for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75625201/6640504? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Agree with @user6910411, you have to call apply method directly on the function.
So, your code will be.

**UDF in Scala:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object ScalaPySparkUDFs {

    def testFunction1(x: Int): Int = { x * 2 }

    def getFun(): UserDefinedFunction = udf(testFunction1 _ )
}
```

**PySpark code:**

```
def test_udf(col):
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    _test_udf = sc._jvm.com.test.ScalaPySparkUDFs.getFun()
    return Column(_test_udf.apply(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))


row = Row("Value")
numbers = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4]).map(row).toDF()
numbers.withColumn("Result", test_udf(numbers['Value']))
```

Comment: I want to pass multiple columns, Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: When I am running this, I am getting TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable