# Error of Using Scala UDF in Pyspark : Method apply([class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper]) does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, pyspark, sbt

I have the Pyspark Program with several UDF Functions. To improve its performance I decided to write UDF functions in Scala and use its Jar file in Pyspark. So, for one of the UDF Function in Scala which converts Persian Date to Gregorian I did these steps.

***First***, I wrote the Scala function in Intellij which is in the following:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1
  import com.bahmanm.persianutils.DateConverter._

  class dateconverter extends UDF1[String, String] {

     override def call(ds: String): String = {
       val year = ds.substring(0, 4)
       val month = ds.substring(4, 6)
       val day = ds.substring(6, 8)
       val outputDate = s"$year/$month/$day"
       println(outputDate)
       val pDate4 = SimpleDate(outputDate) // initialising from a String
       println("Date : "+pDate4)
       persianToGregorian(pDate4).toString()
     }
   }
```

Moreover, I have the `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt` in the Scala project structure. `build.sbt` is in following:

```
  name := "UDFLib"

  version := "0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

  val root = project.in(file("."))
      .settings(Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
       "com.bahmanm" %% "persianutils" % "4.0"
       ))
     )
```

`plugins.sbt` has this contents:

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "2.1.1")
```

After that, I run this command in Terminal:

```
 sbt clean assembly
```

Then I copy the Jar file in the Pyspark project folder and set the program like this:

```
 conf = SparkConf() \
        .setAppName(appname) \
        .setMaster(master) \
        .set("spark.jars", driver)\
        .set("spark.jars","./UDFLib-assembly-0.1.jar")

 from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq
 def datecovert(data):
    logFeaturesUDF = spark._jvm.dateconverter()
     return Column(logFeaturesUDF.apply(_to_seq(spark.sparkContext, [data], _to_java_column)))

 df.select(datecovert(col("persian_date"))).show()
```

When I run Pyspark program I receive this error:

```
   An error occurred while calling o809.apply. Trace:
   py4j.Py4JException: Method apply([class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper]) does not exist
  at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
  at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
  at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
  at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
  at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
  at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Would you please guide me what is the correct way to create a Scala UDF Jar file to use in Pyspark program?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

I change the Scala program like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import com.bahmanm.persianutils.DateConverter._

object dateconverter extends Serializable {
def convert(ds: String): SimpleDate = {
   val year = ds.substring(0, 4)
   val month = ds.substring(4, 6)
   val day = ds.substring(6, 8)
   val outputDate = s"$year/$month/$day"
   val pDate4 = SimpleDate(outputDate) // initialising from a String
   persianToGregorian(pDate4)
 }
def call = udf { x: String => convert(x)}
}
```

Then in Pyspark I use this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq
def datecovert(data):
    t1 = spark._jvm.dateconverter.call()
    return Column(t1.apply(_to_seq(spark, [data], _to_java_column)))

df = df.withColumn("persian_date_milady", datecovert(df['persian_date']))
df.select('persian_date','persian_date_milady').show()
```

But, I want **persian_date_milady** to be a **date** field not **struct** field to insert in Oracle not this one:

```
 root
 |-- persian_date_milady: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
```

If your function has no arguments, you should follow this way:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
 import org.bson.types.ObjectId
 object CreateObjectId extends Serializable {
 def call = udf { () => ObjectId.get().toString }
  }
```

Then after running `sbt clean assembly` and copy ***jar file*** in the Pyspark program. I add this code:

```
 from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq
 def createObjectId():
     t1 = spark._jvm.CreateObjectId.call()
     return Column(t1.apply(_to_seq(spark, [], _to_java_column)))
     df = df.withColumn('guid',createObjectId())
     df.select('guid').show(truncate=False)
```

By the way, `build.sbt` is like this:

```
name := "CreateObjectId"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

val root = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(Seq(
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
    "org.mongodb" % "bson" % "2.3"
    ),assembly / assemblyJarName := "createobjectid.jar")
  )
```