# How to use custom user-defined functions across Jupyter Notebooks in EMR clusters?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I want to share udfs I created in Scala with other cluster which our data scientist use with pyspark and jupyter in EMR clusters.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a Scala UDF in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780141/using-a-scala-udf-in-pyspark)

Comment: @zeapo Don't think so as it's about sharing UDFs in Jupyter across EMR cluster that could give a feature like this. It's not possible in Spark directly *unless* people use shared `SparkSession` in Spark Thrift Server though.

Comment: It's not, because I want to be able to share existing function and add them to the spark catalog, instead of recreate them every time

Comment: Do you want to share the same UDF across different EMR clusters (which I believe are therefore different SparkContexts)? Unless EMR _somehow_ gives you the UDF sharing feature it's not possible in Spark SQL.

Comment: Isn't there something similar to a shared hive metastore? Or add something to spark-default.conf file?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I believe that the OP just wants to share the code library and add to his notebook/dashboard environment

Answer (score 1):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189626/4039014) indeed helps

create an uber jar, put in s3, on bootstrap action copt it from s3 to spark local jar folder and it should work