# Import custom udf from jar to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, jupyter-notebook, user-defined-functions

I am using Jupyter notebook for running Spark. My problem arises when I am trying to register a UDF from my custom imported jar.

This is how I create th UDF in my custom jar:

```java
package com.udf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
  
public class TestUDF implements UDF1<String,String> {

   public String call(String arg) throws Exception {
      return doSomehing(arg);
}
...
```

then I try to import it like this in Jupyter notebook

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
.master("yarn")
.appName("Spark SQL")
.config("spark.jars", "/user/.../test.udf.jar")
.getOrCreate()
```

or like this

```
spark.sparkContext.addJar("/user/.../test.udf.jar")
```

Not sure if these imports work fine but there is no error message at least. Then trying to register my udf like this

```
spark.udf.register("myUDF", TestUDF.call)
```

I get an error message:

> not found: value TestUDF

(Tried some other names but also not found)

This approach seems legit. But I couldn't find explanations about both importing jar and accessing udf from it. Am I missing something important? Could anyone help me with this?

Edit:

Maybe TestUDF should be explicitly imported like this

```
import com.udf.TestUDF
```

but this import attempt returns an error: `object udf is not a member of package com`

and registering

```
spark.udf.register("myUDF", new TestUDF(), StringType)
```

returns `not found: type TestUDF`

Comment: Have you tried : `spark.udf.register("myUDF", new TestUDF(), StringType)`?

Comment: I've seen reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771895/how-to-register-the-java-spark-udf-in-spark-shell but it's not checked as a solution and also there's an import from console not Jupyter

Comment: @blackbishop error message is "not fount: type TestUDF "

Answer (score 1):

Try first importing your jar file by using sparkContext

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("yourjarfilepath")
```

then

```
spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("UDF1","com.udf.UDF1",StringType())
```