# Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have this python code that runs locally in a pandas dataframe:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(df
                          .groupby('A')
                          .apply(lambda x: myFunction(zip(x.B, x.C), x.name))
```

I would like to run this in PySpark, but having trouble dealing with pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData object.

I've tried the following:

```
sparkDF
 .groupby('A')
 .agg(myFunction(zip('B', 'C'), 'A'))
```

which returns

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

I presume because 'A' is no longer a column and I can't find the equivalent for x.name.

And then

```
sparkDF
 .groupby('A')
 .map(lambda row: Row(myFunction(zip('B', 'C'), 'A'))) 
 .toDF()
```

but get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 77):

Since Spark 2.3 you can use `pandas_udf`. [`GROUPED_MAP`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/da526985c7574dccdcc0cca7452e2e999a5b3012/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L2877-L2954) takes `Callable[[pandas.DataFrame], pandas.DataFrame]` or in other words a function which maps from Pandas `DataFrame` of the same shape as the input, to the output `DataFrame`.

For example if data looks like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a", 1, 0), ("a", -1, 42), ("b", 3, -1), ("b", 10, -2)],
    ("key", "value1", "value2")
)
```

and you want to compute average value of pairwise min between `value1` `value2`, you have to define output schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType()),
    StructField("avg_min", DoubleType())
])
```

`pandas_udf`:

```
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def g(df):
    result = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.key).apply(
        lambda x: x.loc[:, ["value1", "value2"]].min(axis=1).mean()
    ))
    result.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
    return result
```

and apply it:

```
df.groupby("key").apply(g).show()
```

```
+---+-------+
|key|avg_min|
+---+-------+
|  b|   -1.5|
|  a|   -0.5|
+---+-------+
```

Excluding schema definition and decorator, your current Pandas code can be applied as-is.

Since Spark 2.4.0 there is also [`GROUPED_AGG`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/da526985c7574dccdcc0cca7452e2e999a5b3012/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L2956-L2984) variant, which takes `Callable[[pandas.Series, ...], T]`, where `T` is a primitive scalar:

```
import numpy as np

@pandas_udf(DoubleType(), functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def f(x, y):
    return np.minimum(x, y).mean()
```

which can be used with standard `group_by` / `agg` construct:

```
df.groupBy("key").agg(f("value1", "value2").alias("avg_min")).show()
```

```
+---+-------+
|key|avg_min|
+---+-------+
|  b|   -1.5|
|  a|   -0.5|
+---+-------+
```

Please note that neither `GROUPED_MAP` nor `GROUPPED_AGG` `pandas_udf` behave the same way as `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` or `Aggregator`, and it is closer to `groupByKey` or window functions with unbounded frame. Data is shuffled first, and only after that, UDF is applied.

For optimized execution you should [implement Scala `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32100973/6910411) and [add Python wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33257733/6910411).

See also [User defined function to be applied to Window in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48160252)

Comment: This doesnt work. I have spark 2.4 and I get  `Job aborted due to stage failure`

Comment: Using pd inside the function definition of 'g' throws "No module named 'pandas'" error

Answer (score 57):

What you are trying to is write a UDAF (User Defined Aggregate Function) as opposed to a UDF (User Defined Function). UDAFs are functions that work on data grouped by a key. Specifically they need to define how to merge multiple values in the group in a single partition, and then how to merge the results across partitions for key. There is currently no way in python to implement a UDAF, they can only be implemented in Scala.

But, you can work around it in Python.  You can use collect set to gather your grouped values and then use a regular UDF to do what you want with them. The only caveat is collect_set only works on primitive values, so you will need to encode them down to a string.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, concat_ws, udf

def myFunc(data_list):
    for val in data_list:
        b, c = data.split(',')
        # do something

    return <whatever>

myUdf = udf(myFunc, StringType())

df.withColumn('data', concat_ws(',', col('B'), col('C'))) \
  .groupBy('A').agg(collect_list('data').alias('data'))
  .withColumn('data', myUdf('data'))
```

Use collect_set if you want deduping.  Also, if you have lots of values for some of your keys, this will be slow because all values for a key will need to be collected in a single partition somewhere on your cluster.  If your end result is a value you build by combining the values per key in some way (for example summing them) it might be faster to implement it using the [RDD aggregateByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.aggregateByKey) method which lets you build an intermediate value for each key in a partition before shuffling data around.

EDIT: 11/21/2018

Since this answer was written, pyspark added support for UDAF'S using Pandas.  There are some nice performance improvements when using the Panda's UDFs and UDAFs over straight python functions with RDDs.  Under the hood it vectorizes the columns (batches the values from multiple rows together to optimize processing and compression).  Take a look at [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) for a better explanation or look at [user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411)'s answer below for an example.

Comment: How would you simulate panda_udf in Spark<=2.2 (due to company's infra). I would like to parallel process columns, and in each column make use of Spark to parallel process rows. Let's say I have certain stat that I want to apply per column. _collect_list_ gives list, is it efficient to convert to new Spark DF ? def myFunc(d_list): sdf = spark.createDataframe(d_list); return sdf.map(...).reduceByKey(...); and called on two columns df.agg(collect_list('col1').alias('col1'),collect_list('col2').alias('col2') )
  .withColumn('col1_', myUdf('col1')).withColumn('col2_', myUdf('col2'))

Answer (score 22):

I am going to extend above answer.

So you can implement same logic like pandas.groupby().apply in pyspark using @pandas_udf
and which is vectorization method and faster then simple udf.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pandas as pd

df3 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 1, 0), ('a', -1, 42), ('b', 3, -1),
                            ('b', 10, -2)], ('key', 'value1', 'value2'))

from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField('key', StringType()),
                    StructField('avg_value1', DoubleType()),
                    StructField('avg_value2', DoubleType()),
                    StructField('sum_avg', DoubleType()),
                    StructField('sub_avg', DoubleType())])


@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def g(df):
    gr = df['key'].iloc[0]
    x = df.value1.mean()
    y = df.value2.mean()
    w = df.value1.mean() + df.value2.mean()
    z = df.value1.mean() - df.value2.mean()
    return pd.DataFrame([[gr] + [x] + [y] + [w] + [z]])

df3.groupby('key').apply(g).show()
```

You will get below result:

```
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|key|avg_value1|avg_value2|sum_avg|sub_avg|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|  b|       6.5|      -1.5|    5.0|    8.0|
|  a|       0.0|      21.0|   21.0|  -21.0|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
```

So , You can do more calculation between other fields in grouped data.and add them into dataframe in list format.

Comment: How do you modify it for a multi-group by scenario? Let's say there is key1,key2,key3 and  value1, value2 - then if I want to do groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']) then how would you modify the apply function?

Comment: It will be same as above , just need to add more keys to groupby method.

df3.groupby("key1","key2","key3").apply(g).show()

Answer (score 8):

Another extend new in PySpark version 3.0.0:
`applyInPandas`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], 
                            ("id", "v"))  

def mean_func(key, pdf):
   # key is a tuple of one numpy.int64, which is the value
   # of 'id' for the current group
   return pd.DataFrame([key + (pdf.v.mean(),)])

df.groupby('id').applyInPandas(mean_func, schema="id long, v double").show()
```

results in:

```
+---+---+
| id|  v|
+---+---+
|  1|1.5|
|  2|6.0|
+---+---+
```

for further details see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html

Comment: Updated broken link https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html