# How to write Pyspark UDAF on multiple columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have the following data in a pyspark dataframe called `end_stats_df`:

```
values     start    end    cat1   cat2
10          1        2      A      B
11          1        2      C      B
12          1        2      D      B
510         1        2      D      C
550         1        2      C      B
500         1        2      A      B
80          1        3      A      B
```

And I want to aggregate it in the following way:

- I want to use the "start" and "end" columns as the aggregate keys
- For each group of rows, I need to do the following:

  - Compute the unique number of values in both `cat1` and `cat2` for that group. e.g., for the group of `start`=1 and `end`=2, this number would be 4 because there's A, B, C, D.  This number will be stored as `n` (n=4 in this example).
  - For the `values` field, for each group I need to sort the `values`, and then select every `n-1` value, where `n` is the value stored from the first operation above.
  - At the end of the aggregation, I don't really care what is in `cat1` and `cat2` after the operations above.

An example output from the example above is:

```
values     start    end    cat1   cat2
12          1        2      D      B
550         1        2      C      B
80          1        3      A      B
```

How do I accomplish using pyspark dataframes?  I assume I need to use a custom UDAF, right?

Answer (score 9):

Pyspark do not support `UDAF` directly, so we have to do aggregation manually.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def func(values, cat1, cat2):
    n = len(set(cat1 + cat2))
    return sorted(values)[n - 2]


df = spark.read.load('file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/text_file.txt', format='csv', sep='\t', header=True)
df = df.groupBy(df['start'], df['end']).agg(f.collect_list(df['values']).alias('values'),
                                            f.collect_set(df['cat1']).alias('cat1'),
                                            f.collect_set(df['cat2']).alias('cat2'))
df = df.select(df['start'], df['end'], f.UserDefinedFunction(func, StringType())(df['values'], df['cat1'], df['cat2']))
```

Comment: That is great, I will try that out and report back to you, thanks.

Comment: What is `f` in your example?

Comment: Never mind, I see that it is "functions" from pyspark import.

Comment: PySpark now supports UDAFs with help from pandas: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497815/376390).

Comment: This method uses `collect` which brings the data to the driver. This defeats the purpose of spark. In which case, the pandas enabled UDAF mentioned y @Marco might be slightly better. 
But these solutions would not work for me, since my UDF needs to be applied to pyspark dataframes and not pandas.
Is there any other way to apply aggregated UDF on pyspark dataframes?

Comment: @thentangler: UDAFs are aggregate UDFs for.. *pyspark*. https://www.google.com/search?q=pyspark+UDAF+2.4.4