# How to apply windowing function in pyspark over grouped data which needs an aggregation within an aggregation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a complicated winodwing operation which I need help with in pyspark.

I have some data grouped by `src` and `dest`, and I need to do the following operations for each group:
- select only rows with amounts in `socket2` which *do not* appear in `socket1` (for all rows in this group)
- after applying that filtering criteria, sum amounts in `amounts` field

```
amounts     src    dest    socket1   socket2
10          1        2           A       B
11          1        2           B        C
12           1        2          C       D
510          1       2          C       D
550          1        2          B       C  
500          1        2          A       B
80            1         3          A        B
```

And I want to aggregate it in the following way:
512+10 = 522, and 80 is the only record for src=1 and dest=3

```
amounts     src    dest    
522          1        2      
80          1        3
```

I borrowed the sample data from here: [How to write Pyspark UDAF on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187630/how-to-write-pyspark-udaf-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Did you already try anything? Can you share your experiments?

Comment: yes, one second please

Answer (score 3):

You can split your dataframe into 2 dataframes one with `socket1` and the other one with `socket2`and then use a `leftanti` join instead of filtering (works for `spark >= 2.0`).

First let's create the dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([
        [10,1,2,"A","B"],
        [11,1,2,"B","C"],
        [12,1,2,"C","D"],
        [510,1,2,"C","D"],
        [550,1,2,"B","C"],
        [500,1,2,"A","B"],
        [80,1,3,"A","B"]
    ]), 
    ["amounts","src","dest","socket1","socket2"]
)
```

And now to split the dataframe :

**Spark >= 2.0**

```py
df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("socket1", "socket").drop("socket2")
df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("socket2", "socket").drop("socket1")
res = df2.join(df1, ["src", "dest", "socket"], "leftanti")
```

**Spark 1.6**

```py
df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("socket1", "socket").drop("socket2").withColumnRenamed("amounts", "amounts1")
df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("socket2", "socket").drop("socket1")
res = df2.join(df1.alias("df1"), ["src", "dest", "socket"], "left").filter("amounts1 IS NULL").drop("amounts1")
```

And finally the aggregation:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
res.groupBy("src", "dest").agg(
    psf.sum("amounts").alias("amounts")
).show()

    +---+----+-------+
    |src|dest|amounts|
    +---+----+-------+
    |  1|   3|     80|
    |  1|   2|    522|
    +---+----+-------+
```