# How can I define user-defined aggregate functions in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I want make an user defined *aggregate* function in pyspark. I found some documentation for [Scala](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html) and would like to achieve something similar in Python.

To be more specific, assume I already have a function like this implemented:

```
def process_data(df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame) -> bytes:
  ...  # do something very complicated here
```

and now I would like to be able to do something like:

```
source_df.groupBy("Foo_ID").agg(UDAF(process_data))
```

Now the question is - what should I put in place of `UDAF`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example)

Answer (score 2):

**PySpark** does not support **UDAF** directly, so we have to do aggregation manually.

**Reference:**

1. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html
2. [How to write Pyspark UDAF on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187630/how-to-write-pyspark-udaf-on-multiple-columns)
3. [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example)
4. https://florianwilhelm.info/2017/10/efficient_udfs_with_pyspark/