# Accessing broadcast Dictionary from within Dataframe methods in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, broadcast

I have a broadcast a dicitonary that I would like to use for mapping column values in my `DataFrame`. Let's say I call `withColumn()` method for that.

I can only get it to work with a UDF, but not directly:

```
sc = SparkContext()
ss = SparkSession(sc)
df = ss.createDataFrame( [ "a", "b" ], StringType() ).toDF("key")
# +---+                                                                           
# |key|
# +---+
# |  a|
# |  b|
# +---+
thedict={"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"}
thedict_bc=sc.broadcast(thedict)
```

Referencing with a literal or using UDF works fine:

```
df.withColumn('upper',lit(thedict_bc.value.get('c',"--"))).show()
# +---+-----+
# |key|upper|
# +---+-----+
# |  a|    C|
# |  b|    C|
# +---+-----+
df.withColumn('upper',udf(lambda x : thedict_bc.value.get(x,"--"), StringType())('key')).show()
# +---+-----+
# |key|upper|
# +---+-----+
# |  a|    A|
# |  b|    B|
# +---+-----+
```

However, accessing the dictionary directly from the command doesn't:

```
df.withColumn('upper',lit(thedict_bc.value.get(col('key'),"--"))).show()
# +---+-----+
# |key|upper|
# +---+-----+
# |  a|   --|
# |  b|   --|
# +---+-----+
df.withColumn('upper',lit(thedict_bc.value.get(df.key,"--"))).show()
# +---+-----+
# |key|upper|
# +---+-----+
# |  a|   --|
# |  b|   --|
# +---+-----+
df.withColumn('upper',lit(thedict_bc.value.get(df.key.cast("string"),"--"))).show()
# +---+-----+
# |key|upper|
# +---+-----+
# |  a|   --|
# |  b|   --|
# +---+-----+
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** You're mixing up things which belong to completely different context. Symbolic SQL expressions (`lit`, `col`, etc.) and plain Python code.

You are mixing up the contexts. Following line:

```
thedict_bc.value.get(col('key'),"--")))
```

is executed in Python on the driver and is literally a local dictionary lookup. `thedict` doesn't contain `col('key')` (literal, there is no expansion involved) you you always get default value.

Personally I would use a simple `join`:

```
lookup = sc.parallelize(thedict.items()).toDF(["key", "upper"])
df.join(lookup, ["key"], "left").na.fill("upper", "--").show()
```

```
+---+-----+                                                                     
|key|upper|
+---+-----+
|  b|    B|
|  a|    A|
+---+-----+
```

but `udf` (as you've already established) or literal `map` would work as well:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, create_map
from itertools import chain

thedict_col = create_map(*chain.from_iterable(
    (lit(k), lit(v)) for k, v in thedict.items()
))

df.withColumn('upper', coalesce(thedict_col[col("key")], lit("--"))).show()
```

```
+---+-----+
|key|upper|
+---+-----+
|  a|    A|
|  b|    B|
+---+-----+
```

**Notes**:

- Of course if you want to convert to upper case, just use `pyspark.sql.functions.upper`.
- Using `some_broadcast.value` as an argument for the function won't work at all. Variable substitution will applied locally and broadcasting won't be utilized. `value` should be called in the function body, so it is executed in the executor context.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes sense, and yes, I'm a bit hazy on when which context is applied. My actual dictionary (a parameter structure) is a multilevel one. For encapsulated dictionaries, I figured I can just keep using create_map, like you suggested, but what if my parameter dictionary looks like this: 
thedict={"a": ("A","AA","AAA"), "b" : ("B","BB","BBB") }
How do I encode it to access thedict["a"][2]. I'm trying to stay away from UDF for speed reasons.

Comment: Nested dictionaries work pretty much the same way. You can check my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48174437/6910411) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48128037/6910411) and structs are just just `Columns` so this `create_map(lit("a"), struct(lit("A"), lit("A"), lit("AAA")), lit("b"), struct(lit("B"), lit("BB"), lit("BBB")))` would work, but for syntax you'll need `arrays`: `create_map(lit("a"), array(lit("A"), lit("A"), lit("AAA")), lit("b"), array(lit("B"), lit("BB"), lit("BBB")))`. With `from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, struct, array, lit`.

Comment: Apologies for pushing. With your last suggestion, I felt I came close to my final goal: broadcast parameter structure of the form:
`{"a": { "first" : (0.1,0.2,0.3), "second": 0.4 }, "b" : { "first" : (0.11,0.22,0.33), "second": 0.44 } } `
but then I started getting errors like this:
_cannot resolve 'map('first', array(0.1D, 0.2D, 0.3D), 'second', 0.4)' due to data type mismatch. The given values of function map should all be the same type, but they are [array<double>, double]_. 
Does it mean a heterogeneous parameter structure like this is not the right solution?

Comment: That's correct. Heterogeneous structures are not supported. If overall structure is fixed then you can use `struct`. Or arrays like this: `create_map(lit("a"), create_map(lit("first"), array(lit(0.1),lit(0.2),lit(0.3)), lit("second"), array(lit(0.4))))`