# Groupby and UDF/UDAF in PySpark while maintaining DataFrame structure

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark and struggling with a simple dataframe manipulation. I have a dataframe similar to:

```
product    period     rating   product_Desc1   product_Desc2 ..... more columns 
a            1         60          foo              xx
a            2         70          foo              xx
a            3         59          foo              xx
b            1         50          bar              yy
b            2         55          bar              yy
c            1         90          foo bar          xy
c            2         100         foo bar          xy
```

I would like to groupBy product, add columns to calculate arithmetic, geometric and harmonic means of ratings **while also maintaining the rest of the columns in the dataframe**, which are all consistent across each product.

I have tried to do so with a combination of built in functions and UDF. For example:

```
a_means = df.groupBy("product").agg(mean("rating").alias("a_mean")
g_means = df.groupBy("product").agg(udf_gmean("rating").alias("g_mean")
```

where:

```
def g_mean(x):
  gm = reduce(mul,x)**(1/len(x))
  return gm

udf_gmean = udf(g_mean, FloatType())
```

I would then join the a_means and g_means output with the original dataframe on product and drop duplicates. However, this method returns an error, for g_means, stating that "rating" is not involved in the groupBy nor is it a user defined aggregation function....

I have also tried using SciPy's gmean module but the error message I get states that the ufunc 'log' is not suitable for the input types, despite all of the rating column being integer type as far as I can see.

There are similar questions on the site but nothing that I can find that seems to fix this issue I have. I would really appreciate the help as it's driving me mad!

Thanks in advance and I should be able to provide any further info quickly today if I haven't provided enough.

It's worth noting that, for efficiency, I am unable to simply convert to Pandas and transform as I would with a Pandas dataframe...and I am using Spark 2.2 and unable to update!

Comment: What is the 'rating' you are referring to in the function g_mean, it is not defined

Comment: Apologies; the actual function in my code is now presented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example)

Comment: It is a duplicate question, although I am restricted to using Spark 2.2 which doesn't have the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
df1 = df.select("product","rating").rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],(1.0,x[1]*1.0))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]*y[1])).toDF(['product', 'g_mean'])
gdf = df1.select(df1['product'],pow(df1['g_mean._2'],1.0/df1['g_mean._1']).alias("rating_g_mean"))
display(gdf)

+-------+-----------------+
|product|    rating_g_mean|
+-------+-----------------+
|      a|62.81071936240795|
|      b|52.44044240850758|
|      c|94.86832980505137|
+-------+-----------------+


df1 = df.withColumn("h_mean", 1.0/df["rating"])
hdf = df1.groupBy("product").agg(avg(df1["rating"]).alias("rating_mean"), (1.0/avg(df1["h_mean"])).alias("rating_h_mean"))
sdf = hdf.join(gdf, ['product'])
display(sdf)

+-------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|product|rating_mean|    rating_h_mean|    rating_g_mean|
+-------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      a|       63.0|62.62847514743051|62.81071936240795|
|      b|       52.5|52.38095238095239|52.44044240850758|
|      c|       95.0|94.73684210526315|94.86832980505137|
+-------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+


fdf = df.join(sdf, ['product'])
display(fdf.sort("product"))


+-------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|product|period|rating|product_Desc1|product_Desc2|rating_mean|    rating_h_mean|    rating_g_mean|
+-------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      a|     3|    59|          foo|           xx|       63.0|62.62847514743051|62.81071936240795|
|      a|     2|    70|          foo|           xx|       63.0|62.62847514743051|62.81071936240795|
|      a|     1|    60|          foo|           xx|       63.0|62.62847514743051|62.81071936240795|
|      b|     2|    55|          bar|           yy|       52.5|52.38095238095239|52.44044240850758|
|      b|     1|    50|          bar|           yy|       52.5|52.38095238095239|52.44044240850758|
|      c|     2|   100|      foo bar|           xy|       95.0|94.73684210526315|94.86832980505137|
|      c|     1|    90|      foo bar|           xy|       95.0|94.73684210526315|94.86832980505137|
+-------+------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: That's brilliant and clearly works so thank you...I have actually solved the issue in a different way....which I will post as an answer when I get chance shortly.

Comment: Cool, I am interested in seeing the solution. Please share when you can

Comment: Actually thinking a bit more, we don't have to go to RDD probably could use power of product property to calculate geometric mean in df using select and group by I suppose

Answer (score 1):

A slightly easier way than above using gapply:

```
from spark_sklearn.group_apply import gapply
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean
import pandas as pd

def g_mean(_, vals):
    gm = gmean(vals["rating"])
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[gm])

geoSchema = StructType().add("geo_mean", FloatType())

gMeans = gapply(df.groupby("product"), g_mean, geoSchema)
```

This returns a dataframe which can then be sorted and joined onto the original using:

```
df_withGeo = df.join(gMeans, ["product"])
```

And repeat the process for any aggregation type function columns to be added to the original DataFrame...

Comment: Nice. Looks like you are not expecting your data to get big, this is much simpler in this case.

Comment: A couple of points: 1. You are hardcoding your column name within the `g_mean` function. So you cant use it globally for other dataframes? 
2. Your function uses pandas dataframe which is fine if you have very small datasets. It doesnt work for large datasets.