# How to use UDF(user defined function) on spark structured streaming?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have made a little search. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example) tells me that I can use UDF on GroupedData, it works and I can handle those rows and columns in GroupData with my own function.

According to [official tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time). They use groupBy() and window() operations to express windowed aggregations like below.

```
words = ...  # streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }

# Group the data by window and word and compute the count of each group
windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
    window(words.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
    words.word
).count()
```

My questions is that whether there is a way to use UDF on **words.groupBy(
window(words.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes")**. May be code like below? I have tried but it not work.

```
schema = StructType(
    [StructField("key", StringType()), StructField("avg_min", DoubleType())]
)

@panda_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def g(df):
    #whatever user-defined code 

words = ...  # streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }
windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
    window(words.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
    words.word
).apply(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark 3 you can use the `applyInPandas` instead, without explicit `@pandas_udf` (see [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#grouped-map)):

```
def g(df):
    #whatever user-defined code 

words = ...  # streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }
windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
    window(words.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
    words.word
).applyInPandas(g, schema=schema)
```

In this case you'll get Pandas DataFrame and return back the Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Hi, Alex.Thanks for your  reply.  But does this still work for **words.groupBy(window(xx), xx).applyInPandas()**.

Comment: YES it works. I an in Spark version2.4.7 before. But it seem that no window.startTime and window.endTime in df.schema in func g, only timestamp and word.