# Looping over blocks of data

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm an amateur coder and very new to pyspark, I need to convert my python code to pyspark to run over millions of data and i'm stumped on simple things. I need to iterate few operations within blocks of data. I have done it using below code in python, but i cannot understand how to do the same in pyspark. can someone please help ?

Python code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for blockingid,df in old_df.groupby(by=['blockingId']):
    nons = df[df.groupby("country")['country'].transform('size') > 1]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df,nons],axis =0)
```

Sample block of input could be below:

| Name | blockingID. | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name_1 | block_1 | country_1 |
| name_2 | block_1 | country_2 |
| name_3 | block_2 | country_2 |
| name_4 | block_2 | country_2 |

The above code groups each block and removes the countries which have been repeated only once within that block.

I know about window functions in pyspark, but i don't understand how to apply whatever operations within the blocks ( Many more operations to do within blocks) append the output I got to another dataframe. Please help.

Comment: Your python/pandas code should be: `old_df[old_df.duplicated(['blockingId', 'country'], keep=False)]`

Comment: @Corralien the above code will delete the countries which have been repeated more than once. i was trying to acheive the opposite, retain the rows in blocks with countries repeated more than once.

Comment: @Corralien never mind, i thought you were doing drop duplicates, but i see it now.  Thank you.. But i need to know how to iterate within grouped blocks for other functions too..

Comment: you want the same output but with pyspark?

Comment: yes, but more importantly, how to loop over grouped blocks.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example.