# User defined function to be applied to Window in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions, window-functions

I am trying to apply a user defined function to Window in PySpark. I have read that UDAF might be the way to to go, but I was not able to find anything concrete.

To give an example (taken from here: [Xinh's Tech Blog](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html) and modified for PySpark):

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()

a = spark.createDataFrame([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]], ['ind', "state"])

customers = spark.createDataFrame([["Alice", "2016-05-01", 50.00],
                                    ["Alice", "2016-05-03", 45.00],
                                    ["Alice", "2016-05-04", 55.00],
                                    ["Bob", "2016-05-01", 25.00],
                                    ["Bob", "2016-05-04", 29.00],
                                    ["Bob", "2016-05-06", 27.00]],
                               ["name", "date", "amountSpent"])

customers.show()

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-1, 1)

result = customers.withColumn( "movingAvg", avg(customers["amountSpent"]).over(window_spec))

result.show()
```

I am applying `avg` which is already built into `pyspark.sql.functions`, but if instead of `avg` I wanted to use something of more complicated and write my own function, how would I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**:

[SPARK-24561](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24561) - *User-defined window functions with pandas udf (bounded window)* is a a work in progress. Please follow the related JIRA for details.

**Spark >= 2.4**:

[SPARK-22239](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22239) - *User-defined window functions with pandas udf (unbounded window)* introduced support for Pandas based window functions with unbounded windows. General structure is

```py
return_type: DataType

@pandas_udf(return_type, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def f(v):
  return ... 

w = (Window
    .partitionBy(grouping_column)
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))

df.withColumn('foo', f('bar').over(w))
```

Please see the [doctests](https://github.com/icexelloss/spark/blob/328b2c4e09502a66939d47d6967ceea7ceab6c8c/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L2605-L2627) and the [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/683f8da534edafd6fdd9a653e768a7b2c3c79b17/python/pyspark/sql/tests.py#L6519-L6628) for detailed examples.

**Spark < 2.4**

You cannot. Window functions require `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` or equivalent object, not `UserDefinedFunction`, and it is not possible to define one in PySpark.

However, in PySpark 2.3 or later, you can define vectorized `pandas_udf`, which can be applied on grouped data. You can find a working example [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006395/6910411). While Pandas don't provide direct equivalent of window functions, there are expressive enough to implement any window-like logic, especially with [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). Furthermore function used with `GroupedData.apply` can return arbitrary number of rows.

You can also call Scala UDAF from PySpark [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33233737/6910411).

Answer (score 5):

UDFs can be applied to Window now as of Spark 3.0.0.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html

Extract from the documentation:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

@pandas_udf("double")
def mean_udf(v: pd.Series) -> float:
    return v.mean()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "v"))
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('v').rowsBetween(-1, 0)
df.withColumn('mean_v', mean_udf("v").over(w)).show()

+---+----+------+
| id|   v|mean_v|
+---+----+------+
|  1| 1.0|   1.0|
|  1| 2.0|   1.5|
|  2| 3.0|   3.0|
|  2| 5.0|   4.0|
|  2|10.0|   7.5|
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Only `pandas_udf` or `udf` too?