# How to count the number of adjacent values in a Pyspark Dataframe equal to a certain value using a rolling window function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Sample dataframe can be created using:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window

    df = sc.parallelize([['2019-08-29 01:00:00',0],
                          ['2019-08-29 02:00:00',0],
                          ['2019-08-29 03:00:00',0],
                          ['2019-08-29 04:00:00',1],
                          ['2019-08-29 05:00:00',2],
                          ['2019-08-29 06:00:00',3],
                          ['2019-08-29 07:00:00',0],
                          ['2019-08-29 08:00:00',2],
                          ['2019-08-29 09:00:00',0],
                          ['2019-08-29 10:00:00',1]]).toDF(['DATETIME','VAL']).withColumn('DATETIME',col('DATETIME').cast('timestamp'))
```

I want to produce a column with a count equal to the number of occurrences of 0 values within a 3 hour period (+/- 1 hour of the current time inclusive of the current Val). The window can be created using:

```
w1 = (Window()
 .orderBy(col('DATETIME').cast('long'))
 .rangeBetween(-(60*60), 60*60))
```

Desired outcome:

```
+-------------------+---+---+
|           DATETIME|VAL|NUM|
+-------------------+---+---+
|2019-08-29 01:00:00|  0|  2|
|2019-08-29 02:00:00|  0|  3|
|2019-08-29 03:00:00|  0|  2|
|2019-08-29 04:00:00|  1|  1|
|2019-08-29 05:00:00|  2|  0|
|2019-08-29 06:00:00|  3|  1|
|2019-08-29 07:00:00|  0|  1|
|2019-08-29 08:00:00|  2|  2|
|2019-08-29 09:00:00|  0|  1|
|2019-08-29 10:00:00|  1|  1|
+-------------------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 1 entry per **DATETIME**, you can use **lead** and **lag** function to get the previous and next values and then you can count for zeros.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

count_zeros_udf = udf(lambda arr: arr.count(0), IntegerType())

df.withColumn('lag1', f.lag(col('VAL'), 1, -1).over(Window.orderBy("DATETIME")))   # Get the previous value
.withColumn('lag2', f.lead(col('VAL'), 1, -1).over(Window.orderBy("DATETIME")))    # Get the next value
.withColumn('NUM', count_zeros_udf(array('VAL', 'lag1', 'lag2')))                  # Count zeros using the udf
.drop('lag1', 'lag2')                                                              # Drop the extra columns
.show()

+-------------------+---+---+
|           DATETIME|VAL|NUM|
+-------------------+---+---+
|2019-08-29 01:00:00|  0|  2|
|2019-08-29 02:00:00|  0|  3|
|2019-08-29 03:00:00|  0|  2|
|2019-08-29 04:00:00|  1|  1|
|2019-08-29 05:00:00|  2|  0|
|2019-08-29 06:00:00|  3|  1|
|2019-08-29 07:00:00|  0|  1|
|2019-08-29 08:00:00|  2|  2|
|2019-08-29 09:00:00|  0|  1|
|2019-08-29 10:00:00|  1|  1|
+-------------------+---+---+
```

With **pyspark >= 2.4**, you can use **UDF** with **pandas UDF** on window as explained here
[User defined function to be applied to Window in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160252/user-defined-function-to-be-applied-to-window-in-pyspark) . Unfortunately, I dont have pyspark 2.4 or above, therefore I cannot test it.