# Pyspark using Window function with my own function

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, window

I have a Pandas's code that calcul me the R2 of a linear regression over a window of size x. See my code :

```
def lr_r2_Sklearn(data):
    data = np.array(data)
    X = pd.Series(list(range(0,len(data),1))).values.reshape(-1,1)
    Y = data.reshape(-1,1)

    regressor = LinearRegression()  
    regressor.fit(X,Y)

    return(regressor.score(X,Y))

r2_rolling = df[['value']].rolling(300).agg([lr_r2_Sklearn])
```

I am making a rolling of size 300 and calcul the r2 for each window. I wish to do the exact same thing but with pyspark and a spark dataframe. I know I must use the Window function, but it's a bit more difficult to understand than pandas, so I am lost ...

I have this but I don't know how to make it works.

```
w = Window().partitionBy(lit(1)).rowsBetween(-299,0)
data.select(lr_r2('value').over(w).alias('r2')).show()
```

(lr_r2 return r2)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a udf with pandas udf with a bounded condition. This is not possible until spark3.0 and is in development.
Refer answer here : [User defined function to be applied to Window in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160252/user-defined-function-to-be-applied-to-window-in-pyspark)
However you can explore the ml package of pyspark:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LinearSVC
So you can define a model such as linearSVC and pass various parts of the dataframe to this after assembling it . I suggest using a pipeline consisting of stages, assembler and classifier, then call them in a loop using your various part of your dataframe by filtering it through some unique id.