# How do I collect a List of Strings from spark DataFrame Column after a GroupBy operation?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function) (by zero323) is very close to what I want with two twists:

1. How do I do it in Java?
2. What if the column had a List of Strings instead of a single String and I want to collect all such lists into a single list after GroupBy(some other column)?

I am using Spark 1.6 and have tried to use

`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list(Column col)` as described in the solution to that question, but got the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list;
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Error you see suggests you use plain `SQLContext` not `HiveContext`. `collect_list` is a Hive UDF and as such requires `HiveContext`. It also doesn't support complex columns so the only option is to `explode` first:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf());
    SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(
            "{\"id\": 1, \"vs\": [\"a\", \"b\"]}",
            "{\"id\": 1, \"vs\": [\"c\", \"d\"]}",
            "{\"id\": 2, \"vs\": [\"e\", \"f\"]}",
            "{\"id\": 2, \"vs\": [\"g\", \"h\"]}"
    );
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(sc.parallelize(data));
    df.withColumn("vs", explode(col("vs")))
           .groupBy(col("id"))
           .agg(collect_list(col("vs")))
           .show();
  }
}
```

It is rather unlikely it will perform well though.

Comment: Even after adding hivecontext in spark java it is showing collect_set is not found.  
                                                                                                         
 df1.withColumn("difference", size(collect_set("colA").over(Window.partitionBy("colB"))))