# Spark Java - Merge same column multiple rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Java Spark and I have 1 Dataframe like this

```
+---+-----+------+
|id |color|datas |
+----------------+
|1  |blue  |data1|
|1  |red   |data2|
|1  |orange|data3|
|2  |black |data4|
|2  |      |data5|
|2  |yellow|     |
|3  |white |data7|
|3  |      |data8|
+----------------+
```

I need to modify this dataframe to look like this :

```
+---+--------------------+---------------------+
|id |color               |datas                |
+----------------------------------------------+
|1  |[blue, red, orange] |[data1, data2, data3]|
|2  |[black, yellow]     |[data4, data5]       |
|3  |[white]             |[data7, data8]       |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to merge the data to create an 'array' of the same column but from differents rows based on the 'id' column.

I'm able to do it throught UserDefinedAggregateFunction but I can only do it one column at a time and it takes too much time to process.

Thank you

Edit : I'm using Spark 1.6

Answer (score 2):

you can group by "id" and then use `collect_list` function to get the aggregated values.

```
dataframe.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct("color")).as("color"), collect_list(struct("dates")).as("dates") )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but unfortunately, I got a "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list" when I try with collect_list
I'm using Spark 1.6

Comment: did you import the function?? import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Comment: yes I did, I found this answer for the undefined function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324049/how-do-i-collect-a-list-of-strings-from-spark-dataframe-column-after-a-groupby-o
I'm trying to solve it

Comment: if you import function from spark sql it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The actual function that works for me is:

> dataframe.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("color").as("color"),
>   collect_list("date").as("date") )
>   dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframe")

Then create a new query where you can use the struct()

> dffinal = spark.sql(s"""SELECT struct(a.color) AS colors,
>   struct(a.date) AS dates FROM dataframe a """)