# How to create arrays from non-zero DataFrame elements in pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there an inverse function for pyspark.sql.functions.explode? Rather than exploding an array into separate rows in an Apache Spark DataFrame, I need to create arrays based on the non-zero elements stored in a DataFrame.

- Input: DataFrame with columns (key1, key2, array_index, array_value)
- Output: DataFrame with columns (key1, key2, array[]), reducing by the (key1, key2) pairs.

I want to make sure this mapping function is carried out in a distributed fashion on the worker nodes and not in serial fashion on the driver node. The general approach suggested at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/02/10/pyspark-appending-columns-to-dataframe-when-dataframe-withcolumn-cannot-be-used/ looks promising, but I wasn't sure of the best way to address my array creation problem.

Comment: What does `array[]` contain?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099715/pyspark-1-6-1-sql-dataframe-column-to-vector-aggregation-without-hive) and comments...

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, the `array[]` will contain the array_values (doubles) in the positions specified by the array_index integer values, with zeros everywhere else. It looks like I could pass a list of (array_index, array_value) pairs to MLLibs' SparseVector class, but I wasn't sure how aggregate the DataFrame rows into such a list.

Comment: @MaxU, thanks for the link. I'll check those options.