# Spark SQL: Aggregate column values within a Group

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to aggregate the values of a column `articleId` to an array. This needs to be done within a group which i create per `groupBy` beforehand.

My table looks the following:

```
| customerId | articleId | articleText | ...
|    1       |     1     |   ...       | ...
|    1       |     2     |   ...       | ...
|    2       |     1     |   ...       | ...
|    2       |     2     |   ...       | ...
|    2       |     3     |   ...       | ...
```

And I want to build something like

```
| customerId |  articleIds |
|    1       |  [1, 2]     |
|    2       |  [1, 2, 3]  |
```

My code so far:

```
DataFrame test = dfFiltered.groupBy("CUSTOMERID").agg(dfFiltered.col("ARTICLEID"));
```

But here I get an `AnalysisException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'ARTICLEID' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Can someone help to build a correct statement?

Comment: Do you use `SQLContext` or `HiveContext`?

Comment: I'm using SQLContext...

Answer (score 0):

For SQL syntax, when you want to group by something, you must to include this "something" in select statement. Maybe in your sparkSQL code, it's not indicated this point.

You have a similar question so I think it's the solution for your problem [SPARK SQL replacement for mysql GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `collect_list` function, but it's available only if you're using `HiveContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy("customerId").agg(collect_list("articleId"))
```