# How to convert rows into string values in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

### How to convert rows into string values in Apache Spark

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
fruit | name
--------------
fruit | apple
fruit | orange
fruit | mango
```

I want to convert it into this:

```
fruit | string
----------------------------
fruit | apple, orange, mango
```

How can I achieve this in Apache Spark?

Comment: look at `collect_list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARK SQL replacement for mysql GROUP\_CONCAT aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `collect_list`

```
df.groupBy("fruit").agg(collect_list("name"))
```

it will group values and create array of them as a new column.

If you want to have string, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function) question (thanks @mtoto)