# Is it possible to GROUP and SUM by multiple rows in SQL? (If yes: How?)

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table which looks like this:

Current Table: 'original_table'

```
   col_1          col_2             col_3
0  Non-Saved      www.google.com    10
1  Non-Saved      www.facebook.com  20
2  Non-Saved      www.linkedin.com  20
3  Saved          www.Quora.com     30
4  Saved          www.gmail.com     40
```

Can I derive a table such as the following using SQL query?

```
   col_1          col_2             col_3
0  Non-Saved      www.google.com    50
                  www.facebook.com
                  www.linkedin.com
1  Saved          www.Quora.com     70
                  www.gmail.com
```

Basically I am expecting a table to have DISTINCT values from col_1, all corresponding values from col_2 and SUM(col_3) for corresponding values from col_3 in one row.

Additional context: I am running the SQL query in iPython notebook.

Comment: Hint: You can use [group_concat](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat)

Comment: Consult a simple sql tutorial and you will have your answer.

Comment: Sorry! I should have given additional context in my question (just added). I am running my query in iPython notebook. Tried using group_concat it gives me the following error:

`AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'GROUP_CONCAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.`

Comment: a sql query will bring back a number of roes. what should the values of col_1 and col_3 be in your example above? should they be null? or perhaps col_2 should be a concatenation of values, and only 2 rows returned?

Comment: @JonScott: As I mentioned in the expected table..I am trying to get DiSTINCT values from the 'original_table' col_1 to the expected table col_1.
col_3 would be the SUM(col_3) for those corresponding values in col_1 and col_2 would be just the concat of all the corresponding values from col_2.
Yes, Expecting it to return me 2 rows

Comment: Do you have any column to use for order by?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Can I 'ORDER BY col_3 DESC'?

Comment: Not if you want the result to be the same as you have shown.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Do I have to ORDER BY? It can take the default.

Comment: There is no default order. database table are unsorted by nature. Without using an order by, no relational database can guarantee the order of the results it returns.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also before you ask read up more & google more re topics, keywords & error messages. Also you are not clear: do you want a table value that blanks out certain otherwise consecutive values in certain columns, and what are you saying about "one row"? Note that adding "basically" does not magically make things clear, and such use of "basically" basically means "not". Also please clarify in response to comments by editing your question, not via commenting.

Comment: @philipxy: Thank your for your feedback. Super helpful. I'll make sure I follow these moving forward.

Comment: Hi. I hope that includes this post because right now the page--question, comments, answer--it shouldn't have been answered when so unclear--is a mess & not useful. You maybe want the effect of a certain group & order & the SparkSQL equivalent of group_concat, but your question doesn't say that or what you understand & have tried, and moreover from what you seem to have tried you could simply have googled 'spark sql group_concat'.

Answer (score 0):

This question was originally tagged with sqllite as the rdbms
the sqlite SQL is

```
select col_1,group_concat(col_2) as col_2,sum(col_3) as col_3
from yourtable
group by col_1
order by sum(col_3) desc;
```

Now - we know this is spark_sql which does not naively support this type of thing. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function) for an answer

Comment: This would work in normal MySql..but fails in embedded query in a iPython notebook.

Gives me the following error:

`AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'group_concat'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.`

Comment: actually - that should work in sqllite (which is what you tagged)

Comment: maybe you could save the ipnb somewhere and link to that?

Comment: also - maybe you are using spark sql or something? - please can you check exactly what rdbms type you are using?

Comment: Yes, It's Spark sql and data is stored in HIVE tables.

Comment: please update your tags - this information is critical!

Comment: please update tags with just one rdbms - its not sqllite or pandasql.or hiveql