# Listagg Alternative in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to aggregate ASINs , grouping it by customerID like this:

```
Input:
C1 - O1

C1 - o2

C2 - o3

C2 - o4

Output:

C1 - o1, o2

C2 - o3, o4
```

In Redshift, I used to this using LISTAGG function. However, it doesn't seem to be working inSpark SQL. is there an alternative for this in SparkSQL?

Comment: [SPARK SQL replacement for mysql GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysql-group-concat-aggregate-function#32750733)