# Create a new column from existing column. Put values that do not exist in the already existing column. Choose from a list of given values

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, insert, calculated-columns

What I have -

1. I have a spark-sql dataframe(df), which has a column named "Country"+other columns also.
   [df dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro2qZ.png)
2. I have a list of 24 countries.(Note: This can be converted into a dataframe or table, whatever can be feasible for the solution)
   listcountry = austria,india,russia,france,germany

What is my problem?
I need to create a new column('remaining countries') in 'df' which will be having all the countries out of the given 24 countries in the list, **except** the one which is available in df.Country

Expected Solution:
[expected solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQYi6.png)

Note: I prefer pyspark/spark-sql/sql in this solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we combine the results from; [How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table?rq=1) and [How do I create a comma-separated list using a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query), the sql result would be something like;

```
UPDATE df
SET remaining_countries =  (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.country SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM df t1
        LEFT JOIN df t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
        WHERE t2.name IS NULL
    )
where remaining_countries is null
```

However, since you're looking for spark, I recommend further reading here: [Spark SQL replacement for MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640729/spark-sql-replacement-for-mysqls-group-concat-aggregate-function)

Comment: Hi Brandon, 1. I am doing this on Azure Databricks notebook where SEAPARATOR doesn't seem to work. 2. I have my original table with given columns above and another table which has one column country having 24 rows with different countries. How does that work here

Comment: The implication I got from the third link in my answer, is that `GROUP_CONCAT` itself wouldn't work, and that there were a few work arounds that I'm not sure what would be best for you. I've also found https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/concat_ws.html that may work as `CONCAT_WS(',', t1.country)`.
The links you provided were labeled as the current table, and the table you wanted at the end. So the code I provided assumed you had already created the column df.remaining_countries, and just needed it populated.